# Error While creating new project with android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

**Edit: Following is taken from the comments**

Following are my dependencies:

```
dependencies { 
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0' 
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' 
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' 
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1' 
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with` build.gradle` ?

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}

Comment: These are the app level dependencies i implemented inside the app. i added the last gradle    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'  but error is not resolved.

Comment: I have answered the question, you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/?utm_source=android-studio#dependency_conflicts):

> Both your app APK and its test APK share the same classpath. So, **you can get a build error if both APKs depend on different versions of the same library.**

So the fix would be to change your

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0`

**to**

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`

Comment: Great! Remember to click on tick button so that it is approved and others can benefit too

Answer (score 1):

you can also go for this one.

```
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

instead of this,

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'
```