# Android Studio Build failed in Execution - Dependency conflict

Tags: android

I am facing this Error , evertime I Build the Project.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Comment: paste build.gradle dependencies so we can see which dependency is causing the conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this conflict by changing dependency versions in build.gradle file:

It's clear that you are using two different version of dependencies. **26.1.0** and **27.1.1**

change the one with 26.1.0 and make it 27.1.1

build.gradle

[image]

if still you are having problem refer to this [Error While creating new project with android studio 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086012/error-while-creating-new-project-with-android-studio-3-0-1)

Comment: how can i Change version?

Comment: i update my answer with build.gradle location, or press shift twice in android studio and search "build.gradle" choose first option.