# Conflict with dependency after creating new project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I am using android studio 3.0.1
after I created New Project It will give below error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>
> > Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app
> >     (27.1.1) differ. See
> >     https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for
> >     details.

This is my app level **build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {

            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
```

and this is my top level **build.gradle** file

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

as per this post:
[Error While creating new project with android studio 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086012/error-while-creating-new-project-with-android-studio-3-0-1)

I Changed my

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

but as I am using

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

I should not use support library 27.1.1.

How can I resolve this issue

Any help accepted.
Thank you  :)

Comment: Here you have multiple same dependency issue , try to exclude one.

Comment: `targetSdkVersion` has nothing to do with your support library versions. Support library versions are related to `compileSdkVersion`. If `compileSdkVersion` is `26` then support library version should be 26.x.x and if it is `27` then support library version should be 27.x.x

Answer (score 2):

> This is occur due to conflict the multiple library you have added in
>   Gradle file.IF your target version is 26 then you must have to use
>   library for 26 API version. Just go in **Project structure -> .idea ->
>   libraries -> remove the folder**. Restart the android studio or Rebuild
>   and clean the project. Problem will solve do this.

Comment: @Learning Always Please accept the answer if it is helpful to you. so another user can follow this steps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure compileSdkVersion is 27.

You need to exclude support library from espresso-Core as follows:

```
 androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your targetSdkVersion vesion. If its is 26 you should use implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' and if it is 27 you should go with implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'. After that sync the project and if not working try to clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the bottom of `build.gradle` (app level one)

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Credit to [Eugen Pechanec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957234/6478047)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the support library version as 27.

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
```

Change to

```
targetSdkVersion 27
compileSdkVersion 27
```

I think it will solve your answer